# Message Broker Queues and MessageType

Tags: message-queue, activemq-classic, nservicebus, messagebroker

What's the standard wisdom and considerations for dividing up a message queue?

Assuming relatively small number of messages (< 1000/day), does it make sense to combine multiple message types into a single queue and have consumers use selectors to filter them? Or, should a single queue only handle a single message type?

A couple of possible considerations I can think of:

- At least in my limited knowledge of ActiveMQ, it looks like Read/Write security is per queue. So message types that need different Read/Write permissions would need different queues.
- Message Selectors would seem to need a standard header value (MessageType: AbcMessage) to filter on
- An explosion of queues (> 10, > 100, > 1000?) seems to impact performance more than an explosion of messages
- A single message type per queue would seem to be easier to write client code for. Just process each message on the queue. If you want a different message type, subscribe to a different queue.
- ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any given MQ system should be able to handle many millions of messages in any given queue, I would not be concerned at all at voume.

I prefer queues that have distinct real-world meaning rather than worrying about selectors.  I know there are real reasons to use selectors or to consume and re-queue, but I prefer to make the queues distinct and not worry about selection.

Answer (score 1):

Since this wasn't really addressed and you asked about it in your question (and it was something I was searching for when I found this), I thought I could chime in on how I am able to filter messages on a single, heterogeneous queue by type.

If you look [here](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-message-properties.html), you will find a user-defined property is available on all messages called `JMSType`. This is a `String` and is empty by default. When you are sending messages, have your producer set this to an agreed upon value, such as `map` or `text` for example, and then, in your consumer, use a particular message selector depending on what kind of message you want to receive. Using the same examples, it would be `JMSType = 'map'` or `JMSType = 'text'`.

I was able to use this technique successfully with a Java producer and a C++ consumer using the [ActiveMQ-CPP](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/) library.